# Tuple data structure in One Simulator

Tags: java, data-structures, tuples, proto, one-simulator

I want to create a tuple data structure called neighborhood, but there is an error "(and [expected", and after I add () or [] still an error, can you help me?

here the source code

```
protected Tuple<Map<DTNHost, Set<DTNHost>>,ArrayList<Double>> neighborhood;


protected SimBetRouterWithFairRouting(SimBetRouterWithFairRouting proto) {      

    neighboursNode = new HashMap<DTNHost, Set<DTNHost>>();
    indirectNode= new ArrayList<DTNHost>();
    directNode= new ArrayList<DTNHost>();
    this.rLambda = proto.rLambda;
    this.rSigma = proto.rSigma;
    this.a = proto.a;
    this.centrality = proto.centrality.replicate();
    this.similarity = proto.similarity.replicate();
    neighborsHistory = new HashMap<DTNHost, ArrayList<Double>>();
```

//here the error

```
neighborhood = new Tuple<HashMap<DTNHost, Set<DTNHost>>, ArrayList<Double>>;
}
```

Comment: try this `neighborhood = new Tuple<HashMap<DTNHost, Set<DTNHost>>, ArrayList<Double>>(neighboursNode, directNode);`

Comment: it still doesn't work sir, it says Tuple cannot be applied to (java.util.Map<core.DTNHost.java.util.Set<core.DTNHost>>, java.util.ArrayList<core.DTNHost>)